# NoSuchMethod Error in ContentValues.keySet() on old android devices

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror, android-compatibility

I get a weird error when using this function. On new devices and emulator works well but when testing the app on old devices it crashes.. Any clue on what is happening?

```
   public boolean bind(ContentValues values ) throws DatabaseException {
        if (values == null) throw new DatabaseException("Values is null");

        ArrayList<String> columnNames = this.getColumnNamesArray(AppController.getDBO().getDatabase());
        String currentKey = null;

        try {
            for (String key : values.keySet()) {
                currentKey = key;
                if (columnNames.contains(key)) {
                    if (values.get(key ) == null ) {
                        this._properties.putNull(key);
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof String) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsString(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Integer) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsInteger(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Boolean) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsBoolean(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Byte) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsByte(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Double) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsDouble(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Float) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsFloat(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Long) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsLong(key));
                    } else if (values.get(key) instanceof Short) {
                        this._properties.put(key, values.getAsShort(key));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(AppController.DEBUG_TAG, "Exception raised: " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
            throw new DatabaseException(e.toString(),currentKey);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError error) {
            // Raised in old devices:
            Log.wtf(AppController.ERROR_TAG, error.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

The error i get is:

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: keySet

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `keySet()` was added in API 11.  What is your min SDK version?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: So, min = 5, when it runs on any device with sdk < 11, it will crash.

Comment: Of course, when you tested on a device or emulator running SDK 5, you knew this anyway ;) (just being cheeky)

Comment: i set min sdk to 11 and it still crashes, by the way .. what is the min sdk recommended nowadays ?

Comment: On a device running SDK => 11?  Same crash?  I don't think so.  Recommended min SDK is whatever cutoff you want to use for devices which can install your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> NoSuchMethod Error in ContentValues.keySet() on old android devices

This means that you need to use different (workaround) solution for **API < 11** since [keyset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#keySet%28%29) is available from API 11. What about to use [valueSet()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#valueSet%28%29) that is available from **API 1**?

```
// solution for API < 11
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   for (Entry<String, Object> item : cv.valueSet()) {
      String key = item.getKey(); // getting key
      Object value = item.getValue(); // getting value
      ...
      // do your stuff
   }
}

// solution for API >= 11
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   // your current solution
}
```